# Is it true that Robin Williams was turned down from being Hagrid because he wasn't British?

Tags: harry-potter, behind-the-scenes, actors

The Harry Potter movies famously had a British only cast edict. Was this the reason why Robin Williams was turned down to play Hagrid in the movie or was something else at play?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It was one of the reasons, yes, but not the only one.

It's true that because he was not British, he was told outright that it was a no go for him to have the part of Hagrid.

> “Robin [Williams] had called [director Chris Columbus] because he really wanted to be in the movie, but it was a British-only edict, and once he said no to Robin, he wasn’t going to say yes to anybody else, that’s for sure,” said the casting director. “It couldn’t be.”

But had he come in to interview, his chances were fairly slim anyway since

> [Casting manager Janet] Hirshenson said Robbie Coltrane was author J.K. Rowling’s first choice to play Hagrid, anyway.

[Huffpo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/the-real-reason-daniel-radcliffe-was-cast-as-harry-potter_us_585b7664e4b0d9a594572683)

Comment: Who is Hirshenson?

Comment: @iMerchant janet hirshenson, the casting manager guess i should edit that in :P

Comment: Additions that don't appear in the original quote are generally denoted by square brackets, at least in American English. Not sure if that varies in other countries.

Comment: @jpmc26 - It's certainly the case in British English, which I suppose is the pertinent question.

Comment: I do wonder what the excision is though, because without "[director Chris Columbus]" there are clearly words missing from the quote.  The [Williams] is an addition but the [director...] is clearly a substitution, if only for "him" or "Chris".

Comment: @bp. No, you can definitely just say "he called because he really wanted to be in the movie".

Comment: 'England and America are two countries divided by a common language' - [George Bernard Shaw](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74737/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-two-nations-divided-by-a-common-language)

Comment: The square brackets if the first quote were added by huffpo the parentheses in the second quote are mine

Comment: @Jack ok, I can see that.

Comment: My guess is that the brackets replace a pronoun like "him" where prior paragraphs (or sentences in that paragraph) that were not quoted gave the full identification.